# Split up length based on 3 DIFFERENT rules for first, middle and last part

Tags: algorithm

I have following problem:

I have a length and want to split it up into parts and different rules that the first part, any intermediate part and the last part must fulfill.

I've a working solution for the problem if I have one rule that's based on a minimum length, a maximum length and a snap that must be validated for all parts, but now the problem gets more complex and I need to adjust it. Does there exist an algoritm for this problem? Does anyone have an idea?

For example:

- Rule first part: length from 500 - 1000 is allowed in steps of 10
- Rule middle part: length from 300 - 600 is allowed in steps of 10
- Rule last part: length from 100 - 200 is allowed in steps of 10

Idea:
Split up length into parts where you check rule 1 for the first part and rule 2 for all following (you don't know yet if you have reached the last part). Then check rule 3 for the last part if you know you reached the last part. Problem: it may happen that rule 3 says, that the last part is invalid and this could end in a new middle part. Which leeds to further problems...

Let's try the example and try to split up the length of 1500:

1) We split it into 1000 and 500 by using the first rule for part 1 and the second rule for all others

2) We apply rule 3 on the last part => we get 1000 and 200 now and a rest of 300

3) And now? What would be a good logic from here on? I know in this case I would split part 1 into 700 and 300 and and add the 300 to the second part and the result would be 700 - 600 - 200 but how to wrap this into a logic that works with arbitrary rules?

Any ideas?

**Goal**

Splitted parts should be as big as possible at the beginning and only parts at the end should be smaller

**Additional optional conditions**

I'm not sure if this is solveable by 100%. I could add following conditions:

- all rules use the *same* snap, this helps by finding the best last two parts
- min length of each rule is >= than the snap

**Edit**

- Snap means parts must be in steps of the snap. 500 to 1000 with a snap of 10 means 500, 510, 520, 530 ...  980, 990, 1000 are valid numbers
- my preferred solution should be optimised for maximum lengths and as less parts as possible

Comment: When you say there is a snap value, it means that you cannot split at arbitrary points, but only at predefined points, right?

Comment: Correct, added some edit to make the definition a little more strict. I would like a solution that works with any rule, but I would also be content with one that has some restrictions

Comment: Is there any other kind of rules on top of the minimum and maximum lengths? All middle parts have to be same length or they can be any length between middle.min and middle max? Should we optimize for max length or min length? And can you explain what does 'snap' mean exactly?

Comment: @selindek middle parts can be any length but must fulfill the rule and snap means target lengths must be in steps of the snap. Explained this in an edit in my question. And I'm targeting maximum lengths and as few parts as possible.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is an [integer linear programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) (a minimization/maximization subject to a set of inequalities where the variables take discrete values).

Answer (score 0):

1) Assign 500 for the first.

2) Assign 300 for first middle.

3) Keep assigning 300 until what is left if less than 300.

4.1) If what remains is between 200 and 300, increase the first by 100, so that the what remains will be between 100 and 200, then set it as the last.

4.2) If what remains is between 100 and 200, assign it to the last.

4.3) If what remains is between 0 and 100, destroy the last intermediate, and split its length to the first and the last one. First one gets 200 more and what remains to the last one will be 100 more, meaning between 100 and 200, then set it as the last.

comment if not clear

Comment: I added some additional informations. The goal is to have as big parts as possible always and only have smaller parts at the end

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in JAVA. I assume all parameters are multiples of the snap. (If it's not the case then round them before call this method). It simply prints the result into the console. You can also collect it into an array and return it.

```
private void doSplit(int length, int fmin, int fmax, int mmin, int mmax, int lmin, int lmax) {
    int k = Math.max(0, (length - fmax - lmax) / mmax);
    int kmax = (length - fmin - lmin) / mmin;
    boolean found = false;
    while (k <= kmax) {
        if (length <= fmax + lmax + k * mmax && length >= fmin + lmin + k * mmin) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        k++;
    }
    if (!found) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No solution");
    }
    // k is the number of middle parts
    System.out.println("Number of parts: first + last + middle x " + k);
    int leftover = length - fmin - lmin - k * mmin;
    int add = Math.min(fmax - fmin, leftover);
    leftover -= add;
    System.out.println("First: " + (fmin + add));
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        add = Math.min(mmax - mmin, leftover);
        leftover -= add;
        System.out.println("Middle: " + (mmin + add));
    }
    add = Math.min(lmax - lmin, leftover);
    leftover -= add;
    System.out.println("Last: " + (lmin + add));

}
```